# phonenumbers python module not giving correct country code

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, data-cleaning, phone-number

I am trying to use the phone numbers module in python and am stuck with the below issue, it is giving the country code wrongly; both are US phone numbers.Can someone suggest how to proceeed

```
import phonenumbers
print(phonenumbers.parse("+301.795.1400")) 
Output: Country Code: 30 National Number: 17951400 ---Wrong
print(phone numbers.parse("+1301.795.1400")) --- ( After Adding +1 or removing '+'  it becomes correct)
output: Country Code: 1 National Number: 3017951400
```

For example :

```
+44 7923 903949 -- Country Code +44  which is correct
+782-205-2583   --Country Code +7 which is wrong
My expectation is +1 as country code ,phone number as 782-205-2583
```

Answer (score 0):

A plus ('+') means that the following digit or digits are a country code. The Country code for the US is '1' (ie '+1'). You're putting the plus, telling the parser that the next digit or digits is a country code, but then omitting the country code that you need.

It looks to me like the module is working correctly.

see:

https://countrycode.org/

Comment: Thank you, but if I remove '+' , the rest of my data is getting corrupted. Can you suggest me a solution

Comment: What do you mean by 'corrupted'. What are you putting in? What are you getting out? What are you expecting to get out?

Comment: Added example please have a look

Comment: Examples are useful but, like I said above, what are you expecting to get out? In your second example, for instance, what were you expecting?

Comment: sorry added , expected output